# WPF XAML Designer error: VerticalScrollBarVisibility and HorizontalScrollBarVisibilty does not exist in the icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit

Tags: c#, wpf

I have found a source code with a very nice WPF UI that I want to take a look at but when I try to look at one of the main UIs in the project it gives me 2 errors about icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit

What I have tried: I tried downloading ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.dll and adding it as a reference but I found out that it already was there so it didn't help with anything.

The code that gives me the[(click here for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Bqo.png) errors:   x:Class="ViiPer.ViiPerUI" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViiPer" xmlns:avalonedit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"

Answer (score 0):

It seems the link used to return an XML schema but now redirects to the organization's github page. You can try contacting them directly.

The [documentation](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/) hasn't been updated since 2014, so I guess they haven't moved it to a new address.

At the end of the day, it's just a link to the XAML files, so you can probably compile them yourself https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/search?l=XML. Do check the licensing of the project, though.